# ASP.Net web form (C#) - 2 Way Binding

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, web

Trying to figure out how to bind data for updating of records similar to a bound ms access subform.

Ideally I would like all column/rows to be able to be updated automatically as they get filled out. Think of a list of products where you need to update 20 prices at once. I wouldnt want to click an update button 20 times rather have it auto save. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Look at using a GridView with all Rows in Edit Mode: http://highoncoding.com/Articles/219_GridView_All_Rows_in_Edit_Mode.aspx

Comment: The article shows how to display the rows in edit mode but does not solve the updating of the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heres the best solution for doing a bulk update in a gridview.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa992036(v=vs.90).aspx